# Change value in setState when your data is in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I have contactNumber with the data of array, and Im using native-base to view the data.

```
this.state = {
    leadProfile: {
      contactNumber: [
          {
          "lead_contact_number": "0912 312 412312",
          "lead_contact_number_type": {
              "lead_contact_number_type": "Mobile"
          }
      },
      {
          "lead_contact_number": "1231234rqdasd",
          "lead_contact_number_type": {
              "lead_contact_number_type": "Mobile"
          }
      },
      {
          "lead_contact_number": "0325 658 58996",
          "lead_contact_number_type": {
              "lead_contact_number_type": "Mobile"
          }
      }
      ]
    },
    contactNumber1: '',
    contactNumber2: '',
    contactNumber3: '',
    contactNumber4: '',
    contactNumber5: '',
  };
}
```

the contactNumber1,2,3,4,5, this are all the containers when the data is change I want also get the data on the specific field

This is my function and also renderedData ....

arrayOfContacts is my array of data, sorry for the code I know not good work around but this what I think to be coded, feel free if there's good workaround..

The goal in here is to display and change the value of ***lead_contact_number***

```
renderContactForm = () => {

  let arrayOfContacts = _.map(this.state.leadProfile.contactNumber)


  if (_.isEqual(this.state.leadProfile.contactNumber.length, 0) || _.isEqual(this.state.leadProfile.contactNumber.length, 1)) {

    return (
      ...
    )
  } else if (_.isEqual(this.state.leadProfile.contactNumber.length, 2)) {

    return (
     ....
    )
  } else if (_.isEqual(this.state.leadProfile.contactNumber.length, 3)) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Form>
          <Item floatingLabel style={{ paddingLeft: 4 }}>
            <Label style={{ fontSize: 15, color: '#a0a0a0', paddingLeft: 4 }}>
              {arrayOfContacts[0].lead_contact_number_type.lead_contact_number_type}
            </Label>
            <Input
              autoCapitalize="number"
              underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
              onChangeText={(text) => 
              this.setState({
                ...this.state,
                leadProfile: {
                  ...this.state.leadProfile.contactNumber[0],
                  lead_contact_number: text
                },
                contactNumber1: text
              })}
              value={this.state.leadProfile.contactNumber[0].lead_contact_number} />
          </Item>
        </Form>


        <Form>
          <Item floatingLabel style={{ paddingLeft: 4 }}>
            <Label style={{ fontSize: 15, color: '#a0a0a0', paddingLeft: 4 }}>
              {arrayOfContacts[1].lead_contact_number_type.lead_contact_number_type}
            </Label>
            <Input
              autoCapitalize="number"
              underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
              onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({
                ...this.state,
                leadProfile: {
                  ...this.state.leadProfile.contactNumber[1],
                  lead_contact_number: text
                },
                contactNumber2: text
              })}
              value={this.state.leadProfile.contactNumber[1].lead_contact_number} />
          </Item>
        </Form>

        <Form>
          <Item floatingLabel style={{ paddingLeft: 4 }}>
            <Label style={{ fontSize: 15, color: '#a0a0a0', paddingLeft: 4 }}>
              {arrayOfContacts[2].lead_contact_number_type.lead_contact_number_type}
            </Label>
            <Input
              autoCapitalize="number"
              underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
              onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({
                ...this.state,
                leadProfile: {
                  ...this.state.leadProfile.contactNumber[2],
                  lead_contact_number: text
                },
                contactNumber3: text
              })}
              value={this.state.leadProfile.contactNumber[2].lead_contact_number} />
          </Item>
        </Form>
      </View>
    )
  } else if (_.isEqual(this.state.leadProfile.contactNumber.length, 4)) {
    return (
     ...
    )
  } 

}
```

The data will be true on `_.isEqual(this.state.leadProfile.contactNumber.length, 3)`
When I'm trying edit the text field the data is change and back to the default number.

Comment: Hi Mike, try out my solution below and let me know if that helps you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a lot of markup to condense. Let me show you a simpler way to render your form and update the corresponding values. See this sandbox for action: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-hill-i3prc

```
class NumberForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      leadProfile: {
        contactNumber: [
          {
            lead_contact_number: "0912 312 412312",
            lead_contact_number_type: {
              lead_contact_number_type: "Mobile"
            }
          },
          {
            lead_contact_number: "1231234rqdasd",
            lead_contact_number_type: {
              lead_contact_number_type: "Mobile"
            }
          },
          {
            lead_contact_number: "0325 658 58996",
            lead_contact_number_type: {
              lead_contact_number_type: "Mobile"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  }

  handleChange = (e, numberIndex) => {
    const { contactNumber } = this.state.leadProfile;

    const updatedNumbers = contactNumber.map((number, index) => {
      if (index === numberIndex) {
        return {
          ...number,
          lead_contact_number: e.target.value
        };
      } else {
        return {
          ...number
        };
      }
    });

    this.setState({
      leadProfile: {
        ...this.state.leadProfile,
        contactNumber: updatedNumbers
      }
    });
  };

  createForm = () => {
    const { contactNumber } = this.state.leadProfile;

    return contactNumber.map((number, numberIndex) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <input
            value={number.lead_contact_number}
            onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, numberIndex)}
          />
          <label>
            {number.lead_contact_number_type.lead_contact_number_type}
          </label>
        </div>
      );
    });
  };

  render() {
    return <div>{this.createForm()}</div>;
  }
}
```

**Highlevel Points:**

- We will use the contact-array to create the inputs like you did
  initially. But we will use the `index` value provided by `.map()` as
  well.
- We define an event-handler function to update our array-state
  whenever the user enters an input, it accepts an index as an
  argument.
- During the setup of our inputs, we give it an event-listener, pairing
  it with `handleChange()` function, and pass in the `index` of the
  corresponding object we are iterating over in the `.map()`
- This structure lets us effectively update the number for each input
  even when the state value is an array of objects.

Keep your structure like this, and you should be able to freely swap out the mark-up like input and label with your choice of components from whatever library you're using.

Comment: WOW sir +1 great work. I change the e.value.target to e, because the e is the already value. :)

Comment: Question additonal sir, what is the value is null, but I want the text field will appear only one, cause this feature is for edit purpose and add :). I hope you could me :)

Comment: @MikeVictoria awesome! I'm glad this helped you :). Hmm what do you mean by null? Likeee if there is no initial-value, do you still want the input to appear at all?

Comment: @MikeVictoria ahh okay! Try out the updated sandbox :).  This could be what you need. https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-hill-i3prc

Comment: Hi @Christopher Ngo How can I pass the value on each rendered data ? in 
   contactNumber1: '',
    contactNumber2: '',
    contactNumber3: '',
    contactNumber4: '',
    contactNumber5: '', 

If the value is only have 3 data so each value will transfer on contactNumber1,2,3

Comment: @MikeVictoria try this out. Just added the feature u mentioned here :): https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-input-feed-i3prc